# getting json data from tree and feeding through to associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to read a JSON API and parse the data into an associative array but I can't seem to get it to work. I must be doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
   var matchedValues = {};

    $.getJSON(url ,function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            var value = this["value"];
            var climb = this["climb"];
            matchedValues[value] = climb;
        });
    });

    console.log(matchedValues); //Outputs Object{}
```

Any ideas? I don't think I am console logging it correctly or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: ajax is asynchronous...you are trying to log data that hasn't been received yet.

Comment: @charliefl: ajax can be asynchronous, but in this case the function is implemented as a callback, so that should be ok

Comment: can you provide what;s in the data ?

Comment: `console.log` is looking for a string to print. When you call it on an object, it uses the object’s default `toString()` method which, as you can see, is not informative. You really need to serialise the object with something like: `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach from jquery documentation

EDIT:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
var matchedValues = {};
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
items[key] = val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`matchedValues` is an Object not an array. try something `likmatchedValues['your_key']` to get the value.

Comment: What would the `your_key` value be?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the data coming back from the ajax call is a JSON string, which you wish to parse. If that’s the case, then the problem is already solved using JavaScript’s JSON object:

```
var matchedValues = {};

$.getJSON(url ,function(data) {
    matchedValues=JSON.parse(data);
});

console.log(JSON.stringfy(matchedValues)); //Outputs Object{}
```

As you see in the above example, you have to reverse the process in order to print it out.

See [JSON MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, then your data is an `Array` of objects, and you want to consolidate them in a big object. 
If got it right, then use this approach:

```
var matchedValues = {};
$.getJSON("ajax/test.json", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (key in data[i]) {
            matchedValues[key] = data[i][key];
        }
    }
    console.log(matchedValues); //this should print your object.
});
```

The data objects must have different keys or they will be overlapsed.